# Cant get cloudformation template to install apps during deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template, to deploy a windows server and run some powershell commands. I can get the server to deploy, but none of my powershell commands seem to run. They are getting passed over.

I have been focusing on cnit to install my apps, no luck

```
    {
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
    "Description":"CHOCO",
    "Resources":{
     "MyEC2Instance1":{
        "Type":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Metadata" : {
           "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
              "configSet" : {
                 "config" : [
                    "extract",
                    "prereq",
                    "install"
                 ]
              },
              "extract" : {
                    "command" : "powershell.exe -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy - 
   Force remotesigned"
                 },
              "prereq" : {
                    "command" : "powershell.exe -Command Invoke-WebRequest - 
   Uri https://xxxxx.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/chocoserverinstall.ps1 - 
   OutFile C:chocoserverinstall.ps1"
                 },
              "install" : {
                    "command" : "powershell.exe -File chocoserverinstall.ps1"
                 }
              }
           },



   "Properties":{
        "AvailabilityZone":"us-east-1a",
        "DisableApiTermination":false,
        "ImageId":"ami-06bee8e1000e44ca4",
        "InstanceType":"t3.medium",
        "KeyName":"xxx",
        "SecurityGroupIds":[
           "sg-01d044cb1e6566ef0"
        ],
        "SubnetId":"subnet-36c3a56b",
        "Tags":[
           {
              "Key":"Name",
              "Value":"CHOCOSERVER"
           },
           {
              "Key":"Function",
              "Value":"CRISPAPPSREPO"
           }
        ],
        "UserData":{
           "Fn::Base64":{
              "Fn::Join":[
                 "",
                 [
                    "<script>\n",
                    "cfn-init.exe -v ",
                    "       --stack RDSstack", 
                    "       --configsets config ",
                    "       --region us-east-1",  
                    "\n",

                    "<script>"
                    ]]}
                }
                     }     
        }      
        }
    }
```

I'm excepting cloudformation to run thru my metadata commands when provisioning this template

Answer (score 0):

The `cfn-init` command requires the `-c` or `--configsets` command to specify "a comma-separated list of configsets to run (in order)".

See:

- [cfn-init - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html)
- [AWS::CloudFormation::Init - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html)

Comment: Thanks, ive looked into --configset and added configset to my metadata, and referred to it in --configset , still nothing

Comment: Have you tried to view the EC2Configure service and cfn logs in `%ProgramFiles%\Amazon\EC2ConfigService` and `C:\cfn\log`? You can login to the instance to access them.